# qt add library freenect

Tags: qt, ubuntu, libusb-1.0, libfreenect2

I installed libfreenect on Ubuntu 16.04. Then when I added its libraries in Qt, the following error occurred.

I tried adding libusb-1.0. I typed this in the terminal:

pkg-config libusb-1.0 --libs --cflags
-I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -lusb-1.0

- The .pro file:

  QT += core
  QT -= gui

  CONFIG += c++11

  TARGET = 1
  CONFIG += console
  CONFIG -= app_bundle

  TEMPLATE = app

  SOURCES += main.cpp

  win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local  /lib/release/ -lfreenect_sync
  else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/debug/ -lfreenect_sync
  else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lfreenect_sync

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include

  win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/release/libfreenect_sync.a
  else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/debug/libfreenect_sync.a
  else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/release/freenect_sync.lib
  else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/debug/freenect_sync.lib
  else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/libfreenect_sync.a

  win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/release/ -lfreenect_sync
  else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/debug/ -lfreenect_sync
  else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lfreenect_sync

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include

  win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local

  /lib/release/ -lfreenect
  else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/debug/ -lfreenect
  else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lfreenect

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include

  win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/release/libfreenect.a
  else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/debug/libfreenect.a
  else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/release/freenect.lib
  else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/debug/freenect.lib
  else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/libfreenect.a

  win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/release/ -lfreenect
  else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/debug/ -lfreenect
  else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lfreenect

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include

  win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/release/ -lusb-1.0
  else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/debug/ -lusb-1.0
  else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/lib/ -lusb-1.0

  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/include

But again the same error occurs. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is self-explanatory. You don't have `libusb-1.0.0` development package installed (i.e. `libusb-1.0.0-dev`).

First check you have `libfreenect-dev` package installed (note that this is a different package than `libfreenect`). If it's installed, it's likely your `libusb-1.0.0-dev` package is damaged and you should re-install it. If it's not installed, you should install `libfreenect-dev` package.

**Installing `libusb-1.0.0-dev`:**

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0.0-dev
```

**Installing `libfreenect-dev`:**

```
sudo apt-get install libfreenect-dev
```

Note that `libusb-1.0.0-dev` and `libusb-1.0.0` are two *different* packages, also `libfreenect` and `libfreenect-dev`.

Comment: Shouldn't a dependency be automatically installed with the libfreenect package?

Comment: @ddriver I just checked now, you're right. `libfreenect-dev` (not `libfreenect`) depends on `libusb-1.0.0-dev`. Probably OP only installed `libfreenect` and haven't installed `libfreenect-dev`. Thank you any way for pointing it out.

Comment: @masoomi Is `libusb-1.0.0-dev` installed in your Ubuntu?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto yes

Comment: @masoomi Ok. Did you add linker flags in your `.pro` file?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I added libusb1.0. but how can add libusb1.0.0-dev?

Comment: @masoomi Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39850519/edit) and add your `.pro` file.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I write contents of .pro file .. now can you help me?